# How to set cursor:pointer css rule?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to set the style for the cursor, this is part of the scss:

```
 .main_rec {
    width: 312px;
    height: 370px;
    border: solid 1px #dedede;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    a{
      cursor:pointer;
    }
  }
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="main_rec col-md-3">
    <noscript></noscript>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"><a class="td-icon-xs icon-help"></a><a href="#">How to prepare?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason I cannot get the anchor pointer style to work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[There is demo on jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/4p8kvzmh)  It working fine.

```css
.main_rec {
    width: 312px;
    height: 370px;
    border: solid 1px #dedede;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    
  }
  
  .main_rec a{
      cursor:pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main_rec col-md-3">
    <noscript></noscript>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <a class="td-icon-xs icon-help"></a>
        <a href="#">How to prepare?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think the reason is scss. Make sure you have build the scss to css